# CPU utilization during testing in Python?

Tags: python, cpu, cpu-usage, standard-library, psutil

I want to get the cpu usage during testing for my ML model (during a call to `predict`). Here is currently what I am doing. `p` is the current process:

```
start = p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
y_hat = clf.predict(X_test)
print(abs(p.cpu_percent(interval=None) - start)) # prints cpu usage (%)
```

Is this the correct approach or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I like to run `htop` or `top` in a terminal while my model is running to monitor usage.

Comment: I looked into that as well, what is the command to do that for a specific function call (testing on a dataset)? Also, shouldn't that accomplish the same as the above using psutil?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specific command, but you can look for running `python` executable(s). Your example is not equivalent because you are taking two snapshots of cpu percent (before and after) but you do not get cpu percentage _during_ prediction. One possible solution is run `cpu_percent()` periodically in a separate thread.

Comment: I edited the code in my question which I believe captures the cpu usage during the call to predict?

Comment: If your cpu_percent function returns the total CPU usage of all processes, subtracting the original usage before running from the usage after running (what you're doing) should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) is suggested to use **[psutil.virtual_memory()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory)**.

   ```
   import psutil
   mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
   print(mem)
   svmem(total=10367352832, available=6472179712, percent=37.6, used=8186245120, free=2181107712, active=4748992512, inactive=2758115328, buffers=790724608, cached=3500347392, shared=787554304, slab=199348224)

   THRESHOLD = 100 * 1024 * 1024  # 100MB
   if mem.available <= THRESHOLD:
        print("warning")

   # you can convert that object to a dictionary 
   dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())
   ```

---

2. **[psutil.cpu_times(percpu=False)](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_times)** Return system CPU times as a named tuple.

   ```
    import psutil
    print(psutil.cpu_times())
    #scputimes(user=17411.7, nice=77.99, system=3797.02, idle=51266.57, iowait=732.58,      irq=0.01, softirq=142.43, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0)
   ```

---

3. **[os.times()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.times)** Returns the current global process times. The return value is an object with five attributes

   ```
   import os 

    curr_gp_times = os.times()      
    print(curr_gp_times) 
    # posix.times_result(user=0.03, system=0.01, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, elapsed=17370844.95)
   ```

---

> EDIT This may be closer to what you are looking for:

4. **[psutil.cpu_times(percpu=False)](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_times)** Return system CPU times as a named tuple. Every attribute represents the seconds the CPU has spent in the given mode.

   - user: time spent by normal processes executing in user mode; on Linux this also includes guest time
   - system: time spent by processes executing in kernel mode
   - idle: time spent doing nothing

     ```
       import psutil
       psutil.cpu_times()
       # scputimes(user=17411.7, nice=77.99, system=3797.02, idle=51266.57, iowait=732.58, irq=0.01, softirq=142.43, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0)
     ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Isn't virtual_memory().percent associated with ram usage?

Comment: It appears to be from his link. 2 and 3 should get the CPU usage though, just keep in mind they return a time instead of a percentage.

Comment: Yurrofian, it returns usage in bytes as stated in the documentation, there are actually some caveat, depending on the OS it suggests to check this Github file: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/meminfo.py                                                                                                           MEMORY
------
Total      :    9.7G
Available  :    4.9G
Percent    :    49.0
Used       :    8.2G
Free       :    1.4G
Active     :    5.6G
Inactive   :    2.1G
Buffers    :  341.2M
Cached     :    3.2

Comment: I actually added a 4th possibility

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this within your program with a builtin, Python's `resource` module might be of use to you [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html). `psutil` is a good [option](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) (as suggested by Federico) if you're able to install packages.

Outside your program, there are many ways to get CPU usage of an arbitrary process. If you're on *nux and prefer the command line, `top` and similar commands should do the job. On a graphical interface, I personally prefer KSysGuard (I'm on Kubuntu). Gnome System Monitor works as well. On Windows, the Task Manager should suffice.

EDIT: `psutil` seems to return global usages. If you only wanted the usage of your process you'd be better off with `resource` or `os.times`, but if you want total CPU utilization (including other processes) `psutil` is a more robust solution.

For CPU times in `resource`:

```
import resource

resource.getrusage()[0]  # Returns the time in seconds in user mode
# Note that this time accumulates while the program runs,
# so you might want to save its previous value each time you take a measurement
```

Comment: this call requires the who parameter: resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)[0]